# Consolidating row data from DB into a list of dicts

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures, sqlite

I'm reading data from a `SELECT` statement of SQLite. Date comes in the following form:

```
ID|Phone|Email|Status|Role
```

Multiple rows may be returned for the same `ID`, `Phone`, or `Email`. And for a given row, either `Phone` or `Email` can be empty/NULL. However, for the same `ID`, it's always the same value for `Status` and the same for `Role`. for example:

```
1|1234567892|a@email.com| active |typeA
2|3434567893|b@email.com| active |typeB
2|3434567893|c@email.com| active |typeB
3|5664567891|d@email.com|inactive|typeC
3|7942367891|d@email.com|inactive|typeC
4|5342234233|   NULL    | active |typeD
5|   NULL   |e@email.com| active |typeD
```

These data are returned as a list by `Sqlite3`, let's call it `results`. I need to go through them and reorganize the data to construct another list structure in Python. The final list basically consolidates the data for each `ID`, such that:

- Each item of the final list is a `dict`, one for each unique `ID` in `results`. In other words, multiple rows for the same `ID` will be merged.
- Each `dict` contains these keys: 'id', 'phones', 'emails', 'types', 'role', 'status'.
- 'phones' and 'emails' are lists, and contains zero or more items, but no duplicates.
- 'types' is also a list, and contains either 'phone' or 'email' or both, but no duplicates.
- The order of `dict`s in the final list does *not* matter.

So far I have come up this:

```
processed = {}

for r in results:
    if r['ID'] in processed:
        p_data = processed[r['ID']]
        if r['Phone']:
            p_data['phones'].add(r['Phone'])
            p_data['types'].add('phone')
        if r['Email']:
            p_data['emails'].add(r['Email'])
            p_data['types'].add('email')
    else:
        p_data = {'id': r['ID'], 'status': r['Status'], 'role': r['Role']}
        if r['Phone']:
            p_data['phones'] = set([r['Phone']])
            p_data.setdefault('types', set).add('phone')
        if r['Email']:
            p_data['emails'] = set([r['Email']])
            p_data.setdefault('types', set).add('email')
        processed[r['ID']] = p_data

consolidated = list(processed.values())
```

I wonder if there is a faster and/or more concise way to do this.

EDIT:

A final detail: I would prefer to have 'phones', 'emails', and 'types' in each `dict` as `list` instead of `set`. The reason is that I need to dump `consolidated` into JSON, and JSON does not allow `set`.

Comment: So basically you need a way to look up an ID, and see all emails and phone numbers linked to it, as well as the status and  roll ?

Comment: @dermen, pretty much, go through all the returned rows, link relevant details to each ID.

Comment: is ```results``` a 2d list ? If so, I have a solution below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When faced with something like this I usually use:

```
processed = collections.defaultdict(lambda:{'phone':set(),'email':set(),'status':None,'type':set()})
```

and then something like:

```
for r in results:
  for field in ['Phone','Email']:
    if r[field]:
      processed[r['ID']][field.lower()].add(r[field])
      processed[r['ID']]['type'].add(field.lower())
```

Finally, you can dump it into a dictionary or a list:

```
a_list = processed.items()
a_dict = dict(a_list)
```

Regarding the JSON problem with sets, you can either convert the sets to lists right before serializing or write a custom encoder (very useful!). Here is an example of one I have for dates extended to handle sets:

```
class JSONDateTimeEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
  def default(self, obj):
    if isinstance(obj, datetime.datetime):
        return int(time.mktime(obj.timetuple()))
    elif isinstance(ojb, set):
        return list(obj)
    try:
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)
    except:
        return str(obj)
```

and to use it:

```
json.dumps(a_list,sort_keys=True, indent=2, cls =JSONDateTimeEncoder)
```

Comment: thanks for suggesting the use of `defaultdict`, I wonder if 'phone' and 'email' fields should be declared as `set` instead of `list`, as there may be duplicates over multiple rows, such as the rows for `ID` 2 in my example above.

Answer (score 1):

I assume `results` is a 2d list:

```
print results
#[['1', '1234567892', 'a@email.com', ' active ', 'typeA'],
#['2', '3434567893', 'b@email.com', ' active ', 'typeB'],
#['2', '3434567893', 'c@email.com', ' active ', 'typeB'],
#['3', '5664567891', 'd@email.com', 'inactive', 'typeC'],
#['3', '7942367891', 'd@email.com', 'inactive', 'typeC'],
#['4', '5342234233', '   NULL    ', ' active ', 'typeD'],
#['5', '   NULL   ', 'e@email.com', ' active ', 'typeD']]
```

Now we group this list by id:

```
from itertools import groupby
data_grouped = [ (k,list(v)) for k,v in groupby( sorted(results, key=lambda x:x[0]) , lambda x : x[0] )]

# make list of column names (should correspond to results). These will be dict keys
names = [ 'id', 'phone','email', 'status', 'roll' ]

ID_info = {  g[0]:  {names[i]:  list(list( map( set,  zip(*g[1] )))[i]) for i in range( len(names))}  for g in data_grouped   }
```

Now for the types:

```
for k in ID_info:
    email = [ i for i in ID_info[k]['email'] if i.strip() != 'NULL' and i != '']
    phone = [ i for i in ID_info[k]['phone'] if i.strip() != 'NULL' and i != '']        
    if email and phone:
        ID_info[k]['types'] = [ 'phone', 'email'  ]
    elif email and not phone:
        ID_info[k]['types'] = ['email']
    elif phone and not email:
        ID_info[k]['types'] = ['phone']
    else:
        ID_info[k]['types'] = []

    # project
    ID_info[k]['id']     = ID_info[k]['id'][0]
    ID_info[k]['roll']   = ID_info[k]['roll'][0]
    ID_info[k]['status'] = ID_info[k]['status'][0]
```

And what you asked for (a list of dicts) is returned by `ID_info.values()`

Comment: @thanks for the answer. Nice to see the use of `groupby` here, I didn't think of it before. However, a couple of problems: 1. by using `groupby`, you rely on that the data are *already sorted* (in this case, by `ID` field). This may not hold for all possible inputs, but can be enforced by the SQL query returning the selection results ordered by `ID`. 2. The structure of `ID_info` in your solution is different from what I proposed, in that every field of each `dict` is now a list whereas I only need 'emails' and 'phones' to be list, also, each `dict` is missing the 'types' field.

Comment: Two minor details to add: in Python 3, `xrange()` becomes `range()`, and `map()` returns a `map` object which is not subscriptable so we need to do `list(list(map(set, zip(*g[1])))[i]` in your example.

Comment: @skyork, groupby should work regardless of the order of the rows, I just tested this in Python 2x. I fixed the answer above to work with Python3x ```map``` and ```range```. Also, added the types entry.

Comment: `groupby` simply goes through the list, whenever the key changes, it creates a new group. For example, if you shift row: `['2', '3434567893', 'c@email.com', ' active ', 'typeB']` to between the rows of `ID` 4 and 5 in the input, the two rows belonging to `ID` of 2 will no longer be grouped together. By 'types', I mean the separate field (of type `list`) in each `dict` called 'types' whose values depends on whether there is any email and/or phone associated with a given `ID`. Please see bullet point #4 in my question.

Comment: gotcha, then I suppose results can be sorted in python, I will add this in!